# Receipt Serial Number in Multi-User Platform

Tags: php, mysql, design-patterns, database-design, transactions

In an multi-seller platform type of application, where there is one database storing all of the transactions of multiple sellers, sequential receipt numbers must be issued by each seller for each sale for record keeping purposes without gaps in the receipt numbering sequence. What schema and approaches could one consider for this requirement?

My initial thought is to create a table with pre-populated sequential serial numbers (and optional prefixes as assigned by the seller) and a status column with values like 'available', 'pending', 'filled' as well as a 'sale_id' that will reference the 'sales' table:

```
table: serial_numbers

id  | seller_id  |  sale_id  |  prefix  |  serial_number |  status
1     1             NULL        NULL       1                available
2     2             1           A          1000             filled
3     1             NULL        NULL       2                available
4     2             NULL        A          1001             pending
5     2             NULL        A          1002             available
```

When a block of serial numbers gets low (say below 10 records available), I would insert 100 new serial number records in the database and set status to available. When a purchase is made, I would begin a new database transaction (which could be rolled back if the process is cancelled or terminated) which would set the next available serial number for the sellers account to pending and if the sale is completed, set the status to filled and relate the 'sale_id' to serial_number record.

Is this an efficient design? Using a simple auto increment is not possible because of the multi-seller constraint on the database. Are there other similar design pattern for multi-seller database applications?

Comment: no, it's not. just use an auto-increment ID, pad them out to a "way more than could never be used in the life of the universe" string, then encrypt/encode the string somehow to diguise that they're number.s e.g. `aes_encrypt('00000000000000001', $key)` -> `randomish looking value`. you'll get complete "garbage" out of it, but it'll be fully reversible so you can get the original serial number back.

Comment: The seller's requirement is that they have receipt numbers that are sequential numbers (without gaps), not some random string.

Comment: they will be sequence in the db. or do you mean you want to re-use the SAME numbers for multiple users, so they're unique only per-user, instead of globally unique?

Comment: Yes, it will re-use the same numbers for multiple users. They will be unique on a per-seller basis. In this case, many users/sellers could have receipt number 1, 2, 3, etc.

Comment: mysql has no direct support for this kind of thing, and pre-populating a table is painful. with appropriate locks/transactions, you can keep a table of `user_receipt_ids`, e.g. `user_id, last_value`, and do a `last_value=last_value+1` type thing.

Comment: I think the +1 approach might expose too many opportunities for collisions.

Comment: why? you'd have one counter per client. and like I said, with transactions/locks, there'd be no way to collide.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I opted to follow Marc B's comments and created a table with a `last_value + 1` approach and incorporated "pessimistic locking" in order to ensure that the sequence of numbers continues without gaps. There are many ways to solve this problem, but this seems to work for my requirements.